# Url.Action not triggering client-side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, client-side, url.action

For some reason I cannot get Url.Action to trigger client-side validation in MVC 2. I have it set up like this

```
<div class="createpage"><a href="<%= Url.Action("Create","Account") %>"></a></div>
```

Where 'Create' is the action and 'Home' is the controller (AccountController.cs). If I put in a regular submit button the validation works just perfectly. I have the validation set up like so

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
    {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummaryJQuery(
    "Please fix the following errors.",
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valSumContainer" /* This is important. You can change the "id" attribute value, but don't remove it */ } }) %>
    <% ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "valSumContainer"; { %>
//Form here
<%}%>
```

Validation set up is from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx.)

The RegistrationModel.cs that I'm getting the validation messages from looks like so

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public class RegistrationModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Username cannot be longer than 25 characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Studio Name is required.")]
    public string StudioName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
    [PhoneNumber(ErrorMessage="Not a valid phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [UIHint("StatesDropDown")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="State is required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip code is required")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Zip code canot be longer than 10 digits")]
    [ZipCode(ErrorMessage="Invalid zip code")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "About text is required")]
    public string AboutText { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Starting price is required")]
    [Currency(ErrorMessage="Not a valid currency value")]
    public double PriceStartsAt { get; set; }

    [UIHint("SkillsListView")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="At least 1 skill must be selected")]
    public IList<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    [UIHint("EquipmentListView")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "At least 1 equipment must be selected")]
    public IList<Skill> Equipment { get; set; }

    [UIHint("OccassionsListView")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "At least 1 occassion must be selected")]
    public IList<Skill> Occassions { get; set; }
}
```

Like I said, with a normal submit button it works just fine (but the client wants their UI so the buttons have to use certain image sprites with CSS.

**EDIT**: Put *HomeController* instead of *AccountController*, fixed

Comment: where is `Home`? you have put `Account` there. is that some mistake?

Comment: EDIT: Forgot to tell what it's doing/not doing; When I click the button nothing happens, no messages are displayed. Which tells me it's not letting the form submit due to empty fields but no errors are being displayed

Comment: @twest I fixed it, it was supposed to be AccountController not HomeController. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PsychoCoder

On the Web, Validation is only fired when a form is submitted.

If you would like to validate using an anchor tag you will need to set up some javascript code. This javascript could be the jQuery Validation Library, alternatively you could call the submit using the onclick event on the anchor.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="this.form[0].submit()">Create</a>`

'this.form[0]' could be replaced with the id of the creation form.

Comment: Well I changed the _BeginForm_ to include the action and controller, removed the Url.Action and added the _onclick_ event and with no text in the anchor (which is how it has to be due to using their UI) it does nothing when I click the image, if I put some text in the anchor (which cannot be there) the Google Chrome JavaScript console gives an error of Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property '0' of undefined, so I dont think I'm getting any closer. I guess I need to do more research on how to accomplish this using the image with an anchor (like it appears I have to do).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I'm getting closer. Changed my *BeginForm* to look like

```
Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "RegisterForm" })
```

Made a click-able DIV tag that would display the image sprite I needed

```
<div onclick="javascript:RegisterForm.submit(); return false" class="createpage">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

So I've got it to submit the form, but no validation is performed at all, even with empty (required) form fields is submits anyways. So what now, this is getting confusing lol. Never had such a hard time submitting & validating a form (then again I'm new at MVC)

Comment: Well I'm kind of an idiot here. Using a normal submit button with the class="classname" did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks t those who tried to help, now I dont know which answer to select as the answer